# How to simplify $\int{\sqrt[4]{1-8{{x}^{2}}+8{{x}^{4}}-4x\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}+8{{x}^{3}}\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}}dx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals, nested-radicals

I have been asked about the following integral:

$$\int{\sqrt[4]{1-8{{x}^{2}}+8{{x}^{4}}-4x\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}+8{{x}^{3}}\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}}dx}$$
**I think this is a joke of bad taste**. I have tried every elementary method of integration which i know, also i tried integrating using Maple but as i suspected, the integrad doesn't have an anti derivative. Any ideas?

Comment: You could always put it into WolframAlpha, see if you get anything remotely nice and if so reverse engineer a solution from there. But be warned: some times WA gives ugly answers when there exist nice ones.

Comment: WA doesn't give anything nice back: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((1-8x%5E2%2B8x%5E4-4xsqrt(x%5E2-1)%2B8x%5E3sqrt(x%5E2-1))%5E(1%2F4))

Comment: All of these kinds of integrals are jokes in bad taste. The universe is laughing at the limited expressive strength of our mathematics.

Comment: Can't the title be more descriptive? .........

Comment: @Mason: WA often gives Wrong Answers, so even if it says something you still have to know how to verify it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use $$\sqrt[4]{1-8x^2+8x^4-4x\sqrt{x^2-1}+8x^3\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}=\left|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right|.$$

Comment: How did you discover that?

Comment: @Arthur I tried to get $(a+b)^4$ under the radical and it turns out.

Comment: Desmos [confirms](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fcphiphvl3) that the two functions are the same.

Comment: It is a single hyperbola like curve with two disconnected parts. Each part can be obtained by changing sign in front of $\sqrt{...}$

Comment: What made you think of that? Pls I need to know.

Comment: @William I want to make denesting. For which I tried to get $(a+b)^4$ under the radical and it turned out.

Answer (score 10):

Hint:

$(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^4 = x^4+4x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}+6x^2(x^2-1)+4x(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}+(x^2-1)^2 = 8x^4-8x^2+1-4x\sqrt{x^2-1}+8x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Let $\text{arcsec}x=t, x=\sec t$

Using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $0\le t\le\pi,t\ne\dfrac\pi2$

$\sin t=\sqrt{\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{|x|}$ as $\sin t\ge0$

$\tan t=\sin t\sec t=?$

$$1-8x^2+8x^4-4x\sqrt{x^2-1}+8x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}=\dfrac{\cos^4t-8\cos^2t+8-4\sin t\cos^2t+8\sin t}{\cos^4t}$$

Now $\cos^4t-8\cos^2t+8-4\sin t\cos^2t+8\sin t$

$=(1-\sin^2t)^2-8(1-\sin^2t)+8-4\sin t(1-\sin^2t)+8\sin t$

$=\sin^4t+4\sin^3t+6\sin^2t+4\sin t+1$

$=(\sin t+1)^4$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{16}{{\left( \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1} \right)}^{8}}=1-8{{x}^{2}}+8{{x}^{4}}-4x\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}+8{{x}^{3}}\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1}$$
So the integral becomes

$$\begin{align}
  & =\int{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{16}{{\left( \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1} \right)}^{8}}}dx} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{2}\int{{{\left( \sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1} \right)}^{2}}dx} \\ 
 & =\int{\left( x+\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-1} \right)dx} \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: While this is nice, I want to warn people that $$f(x):=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}\right)^2$$ is ***not*** the same as $$g(x):=\big|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\big|\,.$$  Over the reals, $f(x)$ is defined only for $x\geq 1$, but $g(x)$ is defined for all $x$ with $|x|\geq 1$.  I subtracted points in the past from students who had written something like this in their homework or exam papers.  (But don't worry, I am not downvoting you.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to deal with such ‘ugly’ integrand,
$$
E(x)=\sqrt[4]{1-8 x^2+8 x^4-4 x \sqrt{x^2-1}+8 x^3 \sqrt{x^2-1}},
$$
where $|x|\ge 1$,

I put $x=\cosh \theta$ into $E(x)$ and then simplify.
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(x)= & \sqrt[4]{ 1-8 \cosh ^2 \theta+8 \cosh ^4 \theta-4 \cosh \theta \sinh \theta +8 \cosh ^3 \theta \sinh \theta }\\
= & \sqrt[4]{ 1+8 \cosh ^2 \theta\left(\cosh ^2 \theta-1\right)+4 \cosh \theta \sinh \theta \left(2 \cosh ^2 \theta-1\right)}\\=& \sqrt[4]{ 1+2 \sinh ^2 2 \theta+2 \sinh (2 \theta) \cosh (2 \theta)}\\=& \sqrt[4]{[\cosh (2 \theta)+\sinh (2 \theta)]^2}\\=&e^\theta\\ \textrm{  OR } E(x) =&x+\sqrt{x^2-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then $$I= \int e^\theta \sinh \theta d\theta = \frac 14\left(e^{2\theta}-2\theta\right) +C= \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2+ x \sqrt{x^2+1}-\ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\right]+C$$

Comment: Nice. The substitution $x = \frac{t^2 + 1}{2t}$ also works (the expression is simplified to $\frac{1}{t} = x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$).